# Is there any way to skip buildRules function checking in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am working on cakePHP 3.7.
I have some validation rules in `buildRules` function. Those are to check the unique `email`. It looks like this .

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email'], 'This email is already in use'));
    return $rules;
}
```

Those are working fine. Now I need to write a function where this validation should not check while saving the data. I can achieve this if I don't use `patchEntity` or `['checkRules' => false]` while saving the data. But the problem is, I need to use `patchEntity` and `['checkRules' => false]` because there are lot more data that need to be validated.
Also I had tried using this.

```
$this->Users->validator()->remove('email');
```

But this is not avoiding the `buildRules` validation checking. Also I can't change or remove `buildRules` validation code as it is getting used in some other function.

Comment: Validation rules applied when patching, and application rules applied when saving are two completely separate concepts, so disabling `checkRules` should be all you need according to your description. If that is not enough, then you're probably talking about validation rules, and you should rephrase your question and add additional information about what exactly your code does, what your data looks like, and what you want / not want to be checked.

Comment: saving data mean edit them ?

Comment: No. Crating the data @Maher